# Matching HTML anchors which display different URL from its href

Tags: regex, postfix-mta, spam, phishing

We're victims of phishing attacks and we want to strengthen our Postfix spam filters.

We want to detect email bodies containing anchors (`<a>`) around an URL but targeting a different URL in its href.

Here's a list of examples:

```
VALID
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
<a href="www.google.com">google.com</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="someId">google.com</a>
<a id="ID" href="https://google.com">google.com</a>

INVALID
<a href="www.malicious.com">www.google.com</a>
<a href="www.malicious.com">google.com</a>
<a href="www.malicious.com" id="someId">google.com</a>
<a id="ID" href="https://google.evil.com">google.com</a>
```

https://regex101.com/r/kZUN84/1

My plan was to create a named capture group containing the domain + TLD (ie. "google.com" for "https://www.google.com"), and check if the text inside the anchor tag matches it. If not, it may be a spam.

As you can see in the regex101 link, I believe I must used capture groups and negative lookahead, but I'm still struggling writing it... (and *I know* URL validation can be tricky)

Any advise to check if a regex matches one of its sub-string ?

Answer (score 1):

I can come up with this, this is matching all the phishing type and not the valid ones. But I think it is prone to false positives like these:

- `<a id="ID" href="https://google.com">google</a>`
- `<a id="ID" href="https://google.com">link here</a>`

Here is the regex:

```
<a\b\s*(?:.*)?(?=\bhref=)href="((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)?+(?'href'(?'start'[^"])[^"]+)"([^>]*)?>((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)?+(((?!\k'href')(?=\k'start'))|(?!\k'href'))([^<]+)(<\/a>)
```

I need the **start** named group to get possible positions in the second link because from there I can check for the whole **href** group. And there is a possibility that the first character in **href** missing so that is why I placed the `|(?!\k'href')`.

https://regex101.com/r/kZUN84/7 (Some of the capture groups are there only for coloring in the regex101)